# Are Android.App.Application activity life cycle callbacks invoked on the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, xamarin

I'm investigating performance degradation that started occurring after an update of a third party library we use (Xamarin.Insights). During my investigation, I stopped the application during a large pause that showed a mutex lock buried within `Android.App.Android.OnActivityDestroyed`.

The call stack shows the library utilises a registered instance of the [`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) interface to track activity lifecycle events in our application. I'm trying to establish if these callbacks are invoked on the UI thread.

Intuitively I think they are invoked on the UI thread but I can't find definitive proof that confirms this.

- Are `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` invoked on the UI thread?
- Could I have a link that provides proof of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily check what thread called the method:

1. Via logging `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, in case of Main thread you'll see something like `Main Thread`.
2. Via checking the Looper of current thread `Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.getMyLooper()`, it'll be `true` in case of Main thread.
3. Via putting a break point to the method and checking thread name in the stacktrace in your IDE/debugger.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I'm going down this path now; building a sample to submit in the bug report I'll be filling with Xamarin.

Answer (score 10):

The callback methods of `Android.App.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` are indeed invoked on the UI-thread.

Implementing the `Android.App.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface and logging the thread IDs for the callback methods show the thread ID is the same as the thread that invokes the `OnCreate` method of an activity:

```
OnActivityCreated on thread 1
OnCreate on thread 1
OnActivityStarted on thread 1
OnActivityResumed on thread 1
```

The sample below to verifies this:

```
[Activity (Label = "UIThreadsCallbacks", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Console.WriteLine ("OnCreate on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}

[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { 
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LifecycleCallbacks());
        base.OnCreate ();
    }
}

public class LifecycleCallbacks : Java.Lang.Object, Android.App.Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public void OnActivityCreated (Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityCreated on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed (Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityDestroyed on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused (Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityPaused on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed (Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityResumed on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState (Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivitySaveInstanceState on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted (Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityStarted on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped (Activity activity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnActivityStopped on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other answer provides a solid method but does not actually answer the question directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is indeed called on UI Thread. ActivityLifecycleCallbacks is called by Activity.onXXX() method. For example, following is source code of Activity.onCreate(). `getApplication().dispatchActivityCreated(this, savedInstanceState);` is to call ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityCreate().
So it is called on UI Thread.

```
@MainThread
@CallSuper
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onCreate " + this + ": " + savedInstanceState);
    if (mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null) {
        mFragments.restoreLoaderNonConfig(mLastNonConfigurationInstances.loaders);
    }
    if (mActivityInfo.parentActivityName != null) {
        if (mActionBar == null) {
            mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = true;
        } else {
            mActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable p = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
        mFragments.restoreAllState(p, mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null
                ? mLastNonConfigurationInstances.fragments : null);
    }
    mFragments.dispatchCreate();
    getApplication().dispatchActivityCreated(this, savedInstanceState);
    if (mVoiceInteractor != null) {
        mVoiceInteractor.attachActivity(this);
    }
    mCalled = true;
}
```